# AJAX Request is hiding text rather than placing the partial

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm trying to implement replies with comments and so when you click "reply" a partial should show up underneath the current comment.

So in my reply.js.erb, I have

```
$("<%= j render(:partial => 'reply', :locals => { :comment => Comment.build_from(@obj, current_user.id, "") }) %>").insertAfter($('<%= @div_id %>')).show('fast');
```

Where @div_id is the division id for the comment that it's replying to. So what's happening right now is that the partial will not display and it's also hiding the content underneath the @div_id. Not sure what's going on.

**EDIT:** So, I believe I figured out why it's being hidden. I have another javascript file in assets called comments.js.coffee which contains this -

```
jQuery ->
  $(document)
    .on "ajax:beforeSend", ".comment", ->
      $(this).fadeTo('fast', 0.5)
    .on "ajax:success", ".comment", ->
      debugger;
      $(this).hide('fast')
    .on "ajax:error", ".comment", ->
      debugger;
      $(this).fadeTo('fast', 1)
```

".comment" is the header for the partial which contains the Reply link. That same partial contains a Destroy link. So somehow when I click Reply it's running this code as well which is hiding the comment afterwards. Here's my partial for comment

```
%div.comment{ :id => "comment-#{comment.id}" }
    %hr
    = link_to "×", comment_path(comment), :method => :delete, :remote => true, :confirm => "Are you sure you want to remove this comment?", :disable_with => "×", :class => 'close'
    %h4
        = comment.user.first_name
        %small= comment.updated_at
    %p= comment.body
    %p= link_to "Reply", comment_reply_path(comment), :method => :get, :remote => true
```

How would I go about fixing this?

Comment: Can you please post the HTML before and after the request?

Comment: How do I do that? Thanks

Comment: IIRC this is the 10 millionth question on Stack Overflow

Answer (score 6, accepted):

May be `@div_id` is not having `#` with it, so below code may work after prepending `#` before `@div_id`

```
$("<%= j render(:partial => 'reply', :locals => { :comment => Comment.build_from(@obj, current_user.id, "") }) %>").insertAfter($('#<%= @div_id %>')).show('fast');
```

Comment: The partial shows but what's in @div_id gets hidden.

Comment: Try this code - `$('#<%= @div_id %>').html("<%= j render(:partial => 'reply', :locals => { :comment => Comment.build_from(@obj, current_user.id, '') }) %>").fadeIn('fast');`

Comment: I figured out the reason why it's hiding but I do not know how to fix it. I updated the question.

Answer (score 3):

Can you try the following?

```
$('<%= @div_id %>').append("<%= j render(:partial => 'reply', :locals => { :comment => Comment.build_from(@obj, current_user.id, "") }) %>").show('fast');
```

## Updated:

can you try `append` instead?

Comment: That does the same. Partial doesn't show up and it hides what's in @div_id

Comment: @Jill, can you try append instead?

Comment: I figured out the reason why it's hiding but I do not know how to fix it. I updated the question.

Answer (score 2):

```
$("<%= j ( render partial: 'reply', :locals => { :comment => Comment.build_from(@obj, current_user.id, "") }) %>").insertAfter($('#<%= @div_id %>')).show('fast');
```

This will work correctly....just syntactical change

Comment: Your updated answer renders the partial correctly however it still hides whatever is found within @div_id

Comment: try this 
$('<%= @div_id %>').insertAfter('HELLO ');
let me know if this works

Comment: I figured out the reason why it's hiding but I do not know how to fix it. I updated the question.